# How to implement bootstrap in opencart theme

Tags: css, themes, opencart

I am Ishika Malhotra, I very new to opencart. I want to make custom themes in opencart using bootstrap 3 technology, I went ahead and followed the few steps below.

1. I made a copy of default theme and created a new theme mytheme
   Catalog>>view>>theme>>default>>
   Catalog>>view>>theme>>mytheme (copied css and images and template folder from default theme)
2. I included bootstrap required files from getbootrap

I  am litte bit confused to start and new theme with bootstrap, I made html themme in bootstrap but not able to create one new theme in opencart with responsive features

I need the know all steps to convert from psd to bootstap, then opencart theme.

Please advise

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are not fixed steps , there are just few things you need to take care of :

- `tpl` files are essentially `php` files and for your case just assume they are `html` files
- Therefore all files in `catalog/view/theme/your_theme/template` are your `tpl` files which you will (may)  need to edit
- your HTML `<head></head>` section lies in `template/common/header.tpl`, so this is the file where you will add (reference) your bootstrap js and css files
- As the name suggest `template/common/` contains html code of parts of page which are common to all pages. e.g. header,footer etc
- Put your bootstrap `css` files in `catalog/view/theme/stylesheet/` folder
- Put your theme specific image files in `catalog/view/theme/image/` folder

That should be all . Just regard your tpl files as html files and do your styling there. Just don't edit/remove anything inside `<?php ?>` tags

Comment: Thanks your quick response. But I get confused with some codes with opencart structure specially with controllers and php codes. Can you help me with that?

Comment: @user3506052 as a theme designer you are not supposed to touch any controller file and not supposed to edit php code inside tpl